# Concatenation is not happening in informatica

Tags: unix, informatica

I have a scenario,

```
P_ID  USER_ID UNIT_NAME
390    ABC    IT
390    PQR    Operations
420    LMT    OPERAITONS
420    PQR    IT
```

o/p

```
p_id user_id  unit_name
390  abc,pqr  it,operations
420  lmt,pqr  operations,IT
```

If i am passing single id like 390 in where condition in sql query in informatica, concatenation is happening but when i am passing entire data(without any where condition) concatenation is not happening.

Comment: I think you’ll need to provide a much more detailed explanation of your issue for anyone to be able to help you. Please provide sample data (formatted so it is  comprehensible), the code you are using, etc

Comment: also if you alreay tried using a mapping, pls share map details as well